# Angular routing not working with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Home page [image: Page1 link click]I am using AngularJS with my ASP.Net MVC application and I am using angular routing but it is not working.

The angular routes are defined as:

```
var app = angular.module("webApp",['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when(
        "/",{
            templateUrl: "home/dashboard",
            controller: "webCtrl"
        })
        .when(
            "/page1",{
                templateUrl: "home/contact",
                controller: "page1Ctrl"
            })
        .otherwise({
                templateUrl: "home/contact",
                controller: "page1Ctrl"
        });
});
```

The navigation links are displayed on `index.cshtml` as given below:

```
<body ng-app="webApp">
    <a href="#/">Home</a>
    <a href="#page1">Page1</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

It displays `dashboard` when launched but doesn't display `contact` page when second link is clicked. Also, it displays strange URLs. On the homepage it dislays `http://localhost:58193/#!/` and when I click on `page1` link URL gets changed to `http://localhost:58193/#!/#%2Fpage1`.Please let me know if I am mistaking anything.

Comment: add screen shot of that you see on the browser along with console errors if any

Comment: Added screenshot. No error displayed in console.

Comment: update your  **asp.net controller , complete code of angular routes.**

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do like this?

```
var app = angular.module("webApp",['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when(
        "/",{
            templateUrl: "/home/dashboard",
            controller: "webCtrl"
        })
        .when(
            "/page1",{
                templateUrl: "/home/contact",
                controller: "page1Ctrl"
            });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/page1" });


  $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
});
```

then:

```
<body ng-app="webApp">

    <a ng-href="#!page1">Page1</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

and maybe put in your index-html in your  section this:

```
 <meta name="fragment" content="!">
   <base href="/">
```

Comment: Thanks Federico! It worked when I changed anchor tag's href to !#page1. However I still wonder why it is showing strange URLs in the browser like http://localhost:58193/#!/(home page) and (http://localhost:58193/#!/page1) for page1.